# hadoop web UI at http://localhost:50070/ doesnt work

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, localhost

command jps shows following details

- 5144 SecondaryNameNode
- 5464 NodeManager
- 5307 ResourceManager
- 5800 Jps

Obviously namenode and datanode are missing

web UI at http://localhost:50070/ doesnt work

but http://localhost:8088/cluster works fine

I am following instructions from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_enviornment_setup.htm

Comment: Tutorialspoint is using an old version of Java and Hadoop.. Please refer to the Apache Hadoop documentation for the version you installed, but since the Namenode and Datanode are not starting, then I'm not sure why you expect that URL to load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Namenode and Datanode is not running. Look at jps(Namenode and Datanode)has to be listed. Otherwise, you won't see it in http://localhost:50070 assuming you configured single node Cluster.

Please check the Namenode and Datanode logs.

Answer (score 1):

as i know Hadoop 3.x.y  it has been changed to

for namenode
http://localhost:9870

with other xml setting,
please see :
https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-apache-hadoop-on-ubuntu-22-04/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34690716)